# Python - Filtering rows using OR condition

Tags: python, pandas

I've a dataframe and I need to make filter based on two conditions:
If first_name = 'Aleshia' OR if last_name = 'Andrade'

I was trying with the code below:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/shanebucket/downloads/uk-500.csv')
data_new = df[df.first_name == 'Aleshia' or df.last_name  == 'Andrade']
print(data_new)
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: `df[(df.first_name == 'Aleshia') | (df.last_name  == 'Andrade')]`

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html?ndexing#boolean-indexing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data_new = df[(df.first_name == 'Aleshia') | (df.last_name  == 'Andrade')]
```

Comment: It gives me this "TypeError: Cannot perform 'ror_' with a dtyped [object] array and scalar of type [bool]"

Comment: I guess you are missing parantheses`()` in the command. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

```
data_new = df.loc[(df.first_name == 'Aleshia') | (df.last_name  == 'Andrade'), :]
```